# Turtlebot3 Gazebo Windows gui error

Tags: gazebo, simulation, turtlebot3, windows

guy! When I try to open gazebo (in windows) for turtlebot3 it doesnt open absolutely nothing. But when I try to launch a simulation it gives me this error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 187, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /home/codebind/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_simulations/turtlebot3_gazebo/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/codebind/.ros/log/9ee83172-c6be-11ee-862c-8c164551edb6/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/codebind/.ros/log/9ee83172-c6be-11ee-862c-8c164551edb6/gazebo-2*.log
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 189, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/codebind/.ros/log/9ee83172-c6be-11ee-862c-8c164551edb6/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/codebind/.ros/log/9ee83172-c6be-11ee-862c-8c164551edb6/gazebo_gui-3*.log.
Please HELP! THX!

Comment: Please use code formatting for the error